# Overfull Title in a Poster

Tags: line-breaking, posters, tikzposter

I'm trying to create a poster with tikzposter, and when I put the title (I know it's too big) it went off the page. I had already tried with `\\`, `\ linebreak`, `\ vspace(4mm)` (I know the last one is not for that). I can't find a solution for it. It is something like:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

%Título, autores e institución
\title{Estimación de la Situación Actual sobre el COVID-19 en México mediante el Modelo Dinámico SIR y su Comparación con Datos Oficiales}
\author{Hi}
\date{\today}
\institute{{University}}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your title in a `\parbox{}{}`

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

%Título, autores e institución
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{Estimación de la Situación Actual sobre el COVID-19 en México mediante el Modelo Dinámico SIR y su Comparación con Datos Oficiales}}
\author{Hi}
\date{\today}
\institute{{University}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]